# Exploring the Replication of Odoo.sh Features and Building a Web Application (Django)

Tags: django, odoo, replication, paas, odoo.sh

I'm interested in replicating the features of odoo.sh. Could anyone provide any valuable resources or links to assist in this endeavor? I've discovered a script that partially automates odoo.sh features, but I intend to create a comprehensive web application (using Python/Django) for this purpose. Is this feasible, and where should I begin? Is there a way to explore the source code of odoo.sh or gain insights into its architecture? Additionally, what other technology stack components should I be familiar with besides Python/Django, Docker, and basic cloud and system administration (e.g., Docker, AWS, etc.)?